# Almost surely constant random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let ($\Omega$, $P$) be a discrete probability space, and $E$ be any set. Now $X$ is a random variable defined on $\Omega$ with values in $E$.

1. If $X$ is almost surely a constant, prove that there exists a unique $c \in E$ with $P(X=c)=1$.
2. If $E=R$ and there exist real numbers $a<b$ such that $P(X \in \{a,b\})=1$, prove that $X$ is a linear combination of a constant random variable and an indicator random variable, where the equality between random variables needs to be interpreted in the "almost sure" sense.

I have trouble working on the concept of almost surely constant random variables, can somebody give me some hints on these two problems? Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of an almost surely constant random variable?

Comment: Actually, my teacher didn't give the accurate definition of almost surely constant random variable, so I follow the definition I found on the internet: "Let $X$ be an almost surely constant random variable. That is, there exists some $c$ such that
 such that: $P(X=c)=1$. But in this case, there's nothing left to prove the first statement...

Comment: I guess you can prove it's not possible to have $P(X=c_1) = P(X=c_2) = 1$ if $c_1 \neq c_2$. But that's quite easy. It's still a strange unclear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition of almost surely constant random variables give in the comments, in the first statement, it remains to check uniqueness of $c$: if $c$ and $c'$ are such that $P(X=c)=P(X=c')=1$, use the fact the intersection of two sets having probability one has probability one.

For the second statement, let $A=\{X=a\}$  and show that $X=(a-b)\mathbf{1}_A+b $  if $X\in\{a,b\}$.